# Short story about gaseous creatures on Jupiter

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find a short story about humans (I think) who were planning to "mine" something from the atmosphere of Jupiter and found unknown gaseous creatures living in the atmosphere. I don't think things ended well for the gaseous creatures. Thank you!

Comment: When did you see or read this story?

Comment: Did it feature a cybernetically enhanced explorer, by any chance? One with a single wheel instead of legs?

Comment: I read it probably 20 years ago. I don't recall a cybernetically enhanced explorer. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Could this be part of the 1982 novel [*2010: Odyssey Two*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010:_Odyssey_Two) by Arthur C. Clarke?

In that novel, aliens turn the planet Jupiter into a star to give more light to the living creatures on Jupiter's moon Europa.  When they do this, they sacrifice the primitive beings that used to live in the atmosphere of Jupiter.

Comment: Clarke used the idea earlier in "A Meeting with Medusa", which did not have the mining bit. Plus they were jellyfish-like, not gaseous.